# Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.deploy.api"}}

Tags: java

I have this error when i'm trying to start my app with jboss 7.1
Caused by:

```sh
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.deploy.api"}}
```

Comment: Hello, do you think we are able to do anything with your question? There is no code, no full stacktrace of any kind. Please help us help you

Comment: Are you upgrading JBoss EAP from 6.x to EAP 7.x?

Comment: no  ! i have tried this solution but it didn't work with me(https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3682621)

Answer (score 0):

There is not module javax.enterprise.deploy.api in path jboss-eap-7.x/modules/system/layers/base/javax.  You have to copy that module in that path or use another version of jboss that contains that module